# windows equivalent of command substitution in makefiles

Tags: windows, makefile, g++, command, substitution

I want to display current build(hg revision) number in the about box of my program. I thought about using a "define" `(std::string rev = REVISION;)` in the code and pass the value to g++ via makefile:

```
$(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o -DREVISION=`hg id -i`
```

would work like a charm, but im developing on windows for windows, so my Q: how to create such a behavior on windows.

Comment: If you are using Cygwin or Mingw, what you have posted should work fine though I think you want -D not -d.

Comment: @Dave of course, sorry was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using g++ then your assumption is mostly right, excepting that passing a macro definition is done using `-D` option, not `-d`. Also, `$(CPP)` in Make usually refers to C PreProcessor. C++ compiler is `$(CXX)`.

```
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp -o main.o -DREVISION=`hg id -i`
```

Regarding command substitution, it should work fine if you run your build in UNIX-ish compatibility layer, like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org). If not, you could avoid using command substitution at all, and pass the result of `hg id -i` to the compiler literally, e.g. as follows:

```
REVISION := $(shell hg id -i)

...
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp -o main.o -DREVISION=$(REVISION)
```